# Python regex negative lookbehind issue

Tags: python, regex

I want to use the python `re` package to search for strings that start with "[[" that is **not** followed by "Category:" has an arbitrary number of characters and end with "]]". I tried the following code:

```
s="blah [[Category:Cartooning]] blah"
regex = re.compile(r"\[\[(?<!Category:).*?\]\]")
res = regex.search(s)
if res!=None:
    print(res)
else:
    print('no match')
```

and got the following response:

```
<re.Match object; span=(5, 28), match='[[Category:Cartooning]]'>
```

Seems like negative lookbehind does not work. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: I think you want to use a negative lookahead `(?!` instead of `(?<!` See https://regex101.com/r/hyz76T/1

Answer (score 0):

You can check using negative lookahead instead. Also check using `is not None`.
Passing and failing text added as well:

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r"\[\[(?!Category:).*?\]\]")

s = "blah [[Category:Cartooning]] blah"
keep = "blah [[Cat:Cartooning]] blah"
texts = [s, keep]

results = [regex.search(i) for i in texts]
for res in results:
    if res is not None:
        print(res)
    else:
        print('no match')
```

Returns:

```
no match
<re.Match object; span=(5, 23), match='[[Cat:Cartooning]]'>
```

Comment: Great, It works. Thank you!

Comment: If you have many lines of text to search, you can also use the re.findall or the re.finditer methods